# Why do diagnolizable matrices have to be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

My professor gave us this definition of a diagnolizable matrix. A matrix $A$ is diagnolizable if it's invertible and

$$(Ax)_{\mathcal{B}} = Dx_{\mathcal{B}}$$

for some diagonal matrix $D$, basis $\mathcal{B}$ and all vectors $x$.

But there are non invertible matrices that have "diagonal equivalents" in other basis. For example,

$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1\\2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ is diagnolizable to $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ even though its not invertible.

So why the restriction on the definition?

Comment: I have never seen anyone use invertibility as part of the definition of diagonalizable...

Comment: This is actually a mistake of mine; I got mixed up, I ( implicitly/subconsciously) confused eigenvector with eigenvalue, so I said below that $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue, when the real point is that $0$ _vector_ is not an eigenvector.

Comment: And I've never seen a definition of diagonizability that only wants an equation like that to hold for _some_ vector $x$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry my wording was wrong, I mean't all $x$.

Comment: I can't believe that your professor told you this.  You must have misunderstood him/her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagonalizable matrices need not be invertible. For instance, the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2\\
1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2\\
1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The converse also need not hold true, i.e., invertible matrices need not be diagonalizable. For instance,
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ is invertible but not diagonalizable.

Diagonalizability and Invertibility do not relate to each other, in general.

Comment: Can you have a non-invertible matrix that is diagnalizable, and the diagnolized matrix has no-zeros in the centre diagonal?

Comment: @dfg A matrix is invertible if and only if all the eigenvalues are non-zero. If a matrix is diagonalized, then diagonal has the eigenvalues. Hence, the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my apologies for my mixup in your other post. Hope this will help clarify the issue:, by solving :$Ax=x$ and $(A-I)x=x$ for $x$.

A non-invertible matrix *can* be diagonalizable. A necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix $A$ to be invertible is that the matrix must have a basis of eigenvectors, so that the dimension of the eigenspace of the matrix must be $\geq n$ , for $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix. Consider your matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1\\2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

Let's compute its eigenspace. first, the eigenvalues. Set:

$Det\begin{bmatrix}2 -\lambda & -1\\2 & -1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}=0$

The characteristic polynomial is : $\lambda^2-\lambda=\lambda(\lambda -1):=0$

Then there are two eigenvalues; $\lambda=1,0$. This guarantees that you have two linearly-independent eigenvectors. Maybe you want to compute the eigenspace associated with each of the eigenvalues.